# Add table row , table data contain drop down which populate from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Add new table row with category, item, measurement, price. I was able to add a new row but was unsure how to populate drop-down data from the database. I have to fetch data for the first row. This is my code.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
<td>
<select id="catid" name="catid[]">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<?php
$getcatid = "SELECT catid,catname FROM category";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$getcatid);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['catid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['catname']; ?></option>
<?php  }?>
</td>
<td>
<select id="itemid" name="itemid[]">
<option value=''>Select Item</option>
</select>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select id="msr" name="msr[]" onchange="showPrice(document.cument.getElementById('itemid').value,this.value)">
<option value=''>Measurement</option> 
</select>
</td>
<td><div  id="price"><input type="text" name="price[]"></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total[]"></td>
</tr>                           
</tbody>
```

This is my script for add & remove row

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-row").click(function(){
        
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td><select name='proid' id='proid'></select></td><td><select></select></td><td><select></select></td><td><input type='text name=''></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td><td><input type='text name=''></td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });
    
    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $("#delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
          if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Please, help me.

Comment: just use clone in jquery. It will clone the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

You need to use `clone()` in jquery.

Here is the jquery script and added working fiddle link.
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rcf24ba9/1/)

```
    $(document).on("click","#add-row", function(){

        var markup = $("table tbody>tr:last").clone();

        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });
    

    
    // Find and remove selected table rows

    $(document).on("click","#delete-row", function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
          if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It will add a whole table body again. how to add the last row only.

Comment: do you want clone last row or first row?

Comment: Previous row only. Your code works but it will add all the rows again.

Comment: @kajol, Answer updated. just change this line only `var markup = $("table tbody>tr:last").clone();`